# How to use Bootstraps utilities to create the badge to show on top of image

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am attaching an image, because I can't seem to get the positioniong correct.  I've been with it all day but can't get it to look like the image attached.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 ps-0">

    <img src="img/image-file.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100 h-100 " alt="Cool image"> 
    <div>the badge text </div>

</div>
```

See the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEw80.jpg).